# How to change html table row color on mouse hover

Tags: html, css, layout, onmouseover, asp.net-mvc-views

I have two different mvc projects in one solution. One is web api project and other is to consume that api. Both have Content folder and Site.css in them. Now in web api consuming project I am showing fetched details in HTML table format like grid. I'm showing individual record details on different view by onclick of record row. Now, before I click the row, I need to change HTML table row (tr) color or style on mouse hover in this consuming project. I have written below css in Site.css in web consuming project Site.css file.

```
tbody tr:hover {
    cursor:pointer;
    background-color:grey;
    color:blue;
}
```

And have referenced the same on Layout view in head section as below

```
<head>
          @System.Web.Optimization.Styles.Render("~/Content/css")
          <link href="@Url.Content("~/Content/Site.css")" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
          @System.Web.Optimization.Scripts.Render("~/bundles/modernizr")
</head>
```

But its not working. Any help please.

Answer (score 1):

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  width: 100%;
}

th, td {
  padding: 8px;
  text-align: left;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #ddd;
}

tr:hover {background-color: coral;}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<h2>Table</h2>    
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>First Name</th>
    <th>Last Name</th>
    <th>Points</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>User</td>
    <td>Name</td>
    <td>Rs.100</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Second</td>
    <td>User</td>
    <td>Rs.50</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Third</td>
    <td>User</td>
    <td>Rs.890</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Last</td>
    <td>User</td>
    <td>Rs.780</td>
  </tr>
</table>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks but am I missing anything in my reference to Site.css? I am putting styles in separate file Site.css. Is the reference link to Site.css correct ?